# When Activity is destroyed on background,how to remove fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

When my app switches to background,the system memory is low, then android will destroy my activity.At that time,I want to remove the fragments attached to activity,so that when activity switches to foreground,I can avoid any abnormal behavior of that activity.I do it like this:

```
@Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        AbstractBaseViewFragment previous = (AbstractBaseViewFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(FRAGMENT_TAG);
        if (previous != null) {
            fm.beginTransaction().remove(previous).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            fm.executePendingTransactions();
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
```

so I want to ask:Are there any other good ideas to finish this target?Will my method cause any crashes?

Comment: When your Activity gets destroyed, fragments inside gets destroyed as well. You don't need to worry about it at all.

Comment: @Varundroid no,if activity gets destroyed on background,when it switches to foreground,the fragments attached to it will auto recreate, unless I remove those fragments

Comment: What you actually trying to do? Why you need to remove Fragments? What's abnormal the Fragment is causing? I think you are looking at the problem from a wrong perspective. If app getting crashed on start after getting destroyed in background then something is wrong with code. I never removed any of my Fragment and all of my apps work fine. Fragment lifecycle is tightly coupled to Activity lifecycle. If Activities gets destroyed, Fragments gets destroyed as well unless you provide me some official docs stating that you need to destroy fragment in code.

Comment: I mean that when user switch my app to background,after a while, the system memories is low,then my activity in my app will get destroyed and as well the fragments attached to activity will also get destroyed.But when user switch my app to foreground, the activity will be restored,then I found the fragments will be auto reattached to activity,but my data related to that is not prepared,so the fragments display abnormal.So I want to remove them first,when activity gets destroyed on background,so that when it switches to foreground,the fragments will not auto be reattached to activity.

Comment: I want to wait the data to be prepared,then I will create fragment and attach to activity,but now it will be automatically,after the activity get destroyed and restored

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: `ft.detach(previous);`

```
if (previous != null) {
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.detach(previous);
                ft.remove(previous);
                ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
... // the rest of your code
            }
```